# Height needs to be defined for hover effect, but this messes up resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div (class: "card") holding an image and some text.  When the user hovers over the card, the height of the image decreases and height of the text increases.  To achieve this effect, I had to set the initial height of the image inside the card.

Problematically, setting the height means that the image is no longer on "auto".  As a result, when I resize my window, the image in the card remains large.  When I zoom in, the image replicates itself, and the text spills over the side of the card.

I do not want these behaviours.  I have created a card on the right that responds to resize and zoom appropriately.  How do I combine the hover effect of the card on the left, and the resize/zoom of the card on the right?

Here's my code:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #212137;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  color: white;
  font-size: 31px;
  text-align: center;
}

div#wrap2 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: "Consolas";
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  fill: white;
}

.imagio {
  height: 75%;
  float: top;
  background-position: center top;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card:hover .imagio {
  height: 10%;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

p2 {
  color: #dedec8;
  font: Ariel;
}

body {
  background-color: #dedec8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <body>


    <div id="wrap2">


      <div class="card">
        <a href="/transitory.pdf">
          <div class="imagio" alt="TrashCan" style="width:100%" height:100px></div>
          <div class="container">

            <p>Characteristics of <br>trash cans</p>
            <p2>Trash cans can be metal, wooden, or plastic. they usually hold plastic bags, which in turn hold all the garbage. Trash is accumulating at an alarming rate.</p2>


          </div>
      </div>
      </a>


      <div class="card">
        <a href="/RRUDesignDraft2.html">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/abstract/" alt="HourGlass" style="width:100%">
          <div class="container">
            <p>How long can you hold it?</p>
            </b>
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>
      </a>



    </div>

    </body?
```

Here's what I've tried:

- introduced `overflow: none;` to the div.  This had no effect on the resizing/zoom problem.
- tried to specify the height in the js, rather than the css: `<div class = "imagio" <img src="trash.png" alt="TrashCan" style="width:100%;height=75%">  </div>` and set the height in the css to auto, but this disappeared the image entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure about the effect you try to achieve but this might work

```css
.card{
    display: flex;
    /*Set column for vertical appearance and row for horizontal*/
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;

    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
}
.image {
    flex: 10;

    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: flex 1s;
}
.text {
    flex : 0;
    overflow: hidden; /*Prevent text overflow*/

    transition: flex 1s;
    text-align: center;
    background: wheat;
}
.card:hover .text {
    flex: 10;
}
.card:hover .image {
    flex: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Sample text to be shown in this snippet</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @mikstime !  I wanted to have the title showing when the page first floats, so I changed `.text {flex :1;}` to text {flex :3;}  Thanks for sharing the info about `flex` and `overflow`!